# Using imp.reload() and open(): Force a file to be read again

Tags: python, python-import

I have a text file with parameters for my code, and I want this text file to be read by my python module every time I reload the module (or run a function within it). The idea is that this way each person using the code can have their own parameter file.

Here is a very simplified example for a text file, parameter.txt, containing two lines:

--------- parameter.txt ---------

```
Redshift [zred]:
6
```

And the beginning of the code:

--------- test.py ---------

```
import re
import linecache as lc

parameter   =       open('parameter.txt','r')
for i,line in enumerate(parameter):
    if line.find('[zred]') >= 0:
        zred = float(re.sub('\n','',lc.getline('parameter.txt',i+2)))
print(zred)
```

'import test as t' gives 6.0

Now, if I change the 6 in parameter.txt to an 8:

'reload(t)' still gives 6.0!

How can I force the 'open' command to happen each time I reload the module?

Comment: Are you on Python 3?  I think that `imp.reload()` probably does not do what you think.  The 3.5 documentation gives:  "*Deprecated since version 3.4: Use importlib.reload() instead.*".

Comment: oh thx, no, I'm on 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Oh wait! I think I found a solution. I had to clear the cache of linecache before using it to get lines from the same text file... sneaky. So, basically adding this line before the loop:

```
lc.clearcache()
```

see [the docs on linecache](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html)